# Custom HeaderView only displayed in last Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom header view for a `UITableView`. The type of the header view is `UITableViewCell`. I implemented it in the storyboard and added it to the view hierarchy like its shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Here is my Code for UITableViewController

```
import UIKit

class SecondCustomTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customHeaderView: UITableViewCell!
    let array = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(SecondCustomTableViewController.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header")

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(array[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        print("\(customHeaderView) -> Section: \(section)")
        return customHeaderView
    }
}
```

When i run it in the simulator it looks like this

[image]

My question is: Why is my custom header view shown for the last section only?

The print statement in the `viewForHeaderInSection` method looks like this:

```
Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7ff287802200; frame = (0 0; 375 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000038d00>>) -> Section: 0
Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7ff287802200; frame = (0 0; 375 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000038d00>>) -> Section: 1
Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7ff287802200; frame = (0 176; 375 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000038d00>>) -> Section: 2
```

I also unwrapped the optional to make it a non optional but its the same behavior. As the print statement shows the `viewForHeaderInSection`method is called three times, so why the header shows up for the last section only?

I hope someone can help me with this.
Every hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you registering it to your tableView and dequeuing it in the method?

Comment: Yes i did. I worked with the same technique in an other project and it worked.

Comment: You don't seem to dequeue in your example though.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you mean, please?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614964-register

Comment: I added the two functions `register(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)` and `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewHeaderFooterView?`but i get this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewHeaderFooterView'. I added it in the `viewDidLoad` as you can see in my edited code
***`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because ui elements cannot be copied, what you are doing is make an instance of UITableViewCell as IBOutlet. Better you can create your view when it needs.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Header") as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    }
```

Hope it helps. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is exactly right. A view has one superview and one position. It cannot be placed at multiple positions at once. To do that, different instances of the same view would have to be created.

Comment: Also i recomend to do an UIView with background color and label inside, is pretty easy and you dont need to create cells with reusable identifiers and other stuff. Just create it programatically\

Comment: I think you are right. I got the register and the dequeue... method working correctly. I tried the following: `let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "Header")
        header?.backgroundView = customHeaderView!`and i got the same behavior. Thank you! Now i know that i can't do it that way

Comment: @lucas-palaian Complex UIs should not be done in code. Xibs and storyboads are one our most powerful tools. The reusing saves up runtime memory.